# Why am I not generating the correct polar coordinate graph?

Tags: java, graphics

I am having some trouble graphing a simple polar equation. The equation is r = cos(3Ѳ). I want to plot each r as theta increments, but instead, I am getting a linear line when it should be something like a 3 petal flower.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;



        double dt = Math.PI / 720;
        int w = getWidth() / 2;
        int h = getHeight() / 2;
        path.reset();
        path.moveTo(w, h);
        for (double t = 0; t < 6 * Math.PI; t += dt) {
            double r = Math.cos(3*t);
            double x = r * Math.cos(t);
            double y = r * Math.sin(t);
            path.lineTo(x, y);
        }
        g2d.setColor(Color.blue);
        g2d.draw(path);
    }
```

Comment: I suspect you want to multiply your `r` by something, say, `h/2`, and add something to your x and y, say, `w/2` and `h/2`. Otherwise you're just going to draw things within 1 pixel of the origin.

Comment: Amazing thanks so much. This did the trick: double x = w * r * Math.cos(t) + w;
            double y = h * r * Math.sin(t) + w;